# Python Pandas: Create a column that sums certain other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe like below, where one column identifies each row and several other columns (below: column1, column2, column3) are binary 1/0.

```
data = np.array([[1,0,0, 0], 
                 [2,0,0, 1], 
                 [3,0,1, 0], 
                 [4,0,1, 1],
                 [5,1,0, 0],
                 [6,1,0, 1],
                 [7,1,1, 0],
                 [8,1,1, 1]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['subject', 'column1', 'column2', 'column3'])
```

I am trying to create a new column (let's call it 'total'), that sums the values of column1, column2, and column3.

So, given the above dataframe example, the desired outcome would look like:

```
| subject | column1 | column2 | column3 | total |
| ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ----- |
| 1       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0     |
| 2       | 0       | 0       | 1       | 1     |
| 3       | 0       | 1       | 0       | 1     |
| 4       | 0       | 1       | 1       | 2     |
| 5       | 1       | 0       | 0       | 1     |
| 6       | 1       | 0       | 1       | 2     |
| 7       | 1       | 1       | 0       | 2     |
| 8       | 1       | 1       | 1       | 3     |
```

I'm not sure how to do this, so would welcome your advice.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the columns

```
df.total = df.column1 + df.column2 + df.column3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `filter` the required columns and evaluate the `sum`.

```
df['total'] = df.filter(like='column').sum(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `set_index` or the `df.drop` function here as they return a copy of the dataframe. Rather use the XOR(`^`) operator to exclude the subject column from the calculation and take a sum on axis=1. Though this also returns a copy but without any extra compute:

```
df['total'] = df[df.columns^['subject']].sum(1)
```

Note that in pandas way we also have [`df.columns.difference(['subject'])`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) which has an additional param of keeping the order (`sort=False`) but I do not think that is required for this usecase.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df['total'] = df[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].astype(int).sum(1)
```